# What kind of seed is most suitable for my lawn?

Tags: grass, fescue

I am trying to figure out what seed is best for my lawn.  I need to over seed -  really, really bad.  And I am unsure what the majority type of grass I have I believe it is Fescue and Centipede (A lot of weeds ton include white clover, dandelion, henbit, and crab grass type weeds).  I live just North of Charlotte, NC in Mooresville, NC.  I am in Zone 8 of this map - http://hancockseed.com/seedinfo/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14&Itemid=60

I have attached some pictures to help explain my situation.  Not to mention I have the NHOA on my back - 'Nazi Home Owners Association' on my back.

I love fescue, but it dies in the heat and the majority is becoming centipede, so how to rid my yard of fescue and just let the centipede take over?  Pictures coming soon.

(If I am wrong about the type of grass please let me know)

Fescue
[image]
Fescue with dormat centipede
[image]
More centipede
[image]
Centipede
[image]

Comment: Hahaha, "NHOA"... good one.

Comment: Hi Moojjoo! I don't know if it's my browser or not, but that link doesn't lead to a map. It leads to a newspaper article about a band going on a trip to China. Would you have a look at it for me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Love the Nazi Home Owner Association, so very true!  What I am seeing is a 'snow mold' problem on your lawn.  You have some preparation to do before seeding.  Removing all of the roots and debris, a little top soil, raked, leveled, ROLLED with a water filled roller...then seeding...

Another idea would be to call a grass spray seeding company.  Very inexpensive.  They'll come out and give you an estimate and instructions for preparation and then watering and growing up to your first virgin mow.  Excellent.  Next step up would be sod.

If your lawn was installed as sod in the first place this might be something to consider.  It is easy, looks kind of complicated right now, but if your lawn was sod I'd look into replacing the dead grass using the same sod.

That sod company would also have lawn grass seed mixture to sell and I would trust their seed over Home Depot's any day.

Next year, do not fertilize with high nitrogen just before winter.  That causes snow molds, red thread...lawn diseases.  You don't want your lawn going into winter with freshly grown vigorous new growth.  (Check out Dr. Earth's Lawn Fertilizer...this stuff blew me away and I KNOW lawns).  Mow your grass no lower than 3 inches.  3.5 inches is better.  Never mow shorter than 3 inches!!  Big Big deal.

Use fall lawn fertilizer formulations only in the fall.  Important to do but make sure the nitrogen is lower than the Phosphorus and the Potassium.  Aerate once per year.  Period.  Soil test before liming.  Water only when you see your footprints stay down on your lawn.  That is when you water DEEPLY.  Don't water again until you see your foot prints stay down on your lawn.  This trains your grass roots to be deep, healthy and able to keep your lawn green during drought.  Saves money on water bills.  One inch per week is your goal.  Water once per week, 1" or twice at 1/2" (measure using straight sided tuna fish or cat food cans).

If you choose to grow via seed you will be watering shallowly 4 or 5 times per day until that grass is ready to mow.  Once you start mowing only water when the new grass blades stay down when you step on it.  You are getting the new grass equal to the older crop's root depth and size.

Look for 'Professional's Choice' Grass seed for cool season lawns.  That is the one I used in the PNW.  Dr. Earth's Lawn fertilizer was so good I used it on all of my client's lawns.  Costs more, you use 2 or 3 applications during the growing season versus 4.  Slower to green but that is a good thing.  It just makes healthy grass and lasts longer use a rotary spreader to apply seed or fertilizer.

Grass companies spray right to your edges perfectly and add a perfect moisture holding mulch just the right amount of fertilizer.  I would call a local grass spray company for sure. They would tell you for free how to prepare your lawn to be 'over sprayed' or they would tell you sod might be a better choice or what seed to purchase.  They test the pH of your soil...they give you a guarantee!

I just checked on your grass mixes in North Carolina.  Centipede is common for warm season grasses, fescue is found in cool season grasses.  Your pictures looked like cool season.  I am so sorry, found an article for you on North Carolina lawn grasses.
[NC lawns](https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/carolina-lawns)

Comment: Thank you for the time and information.  I think I am going to grin and bear it till the fall.  Use some Ortho Weed B Gone https://www.ortho.com/en-us/products/weed-control/ortho-weed-b-gon-plus-crabgrass-control-ready-spray2, then use my spike shoes - https://www.amazon.com/Lawn-Aerator-Spike-Shoes-Effectively/dp/B01HHD0LZ6/ref=sr_1_3/140-7842545-7255131?ie=UTF8&qid=1522951805&sr=8-3&keywords=aerator+spike+shoes then rake up the bare spots put some top soil as you suggested and then overseed with some fescue mix.  Then really work again in the fall.

Comment: Spikes only compact the soil MORE.  You need to remove plugs of grass and soil and leave the plugs to disintegrate on top of the soil.  Spikes just push the soil particles closer together.  Waste of time.  Trust me.  Rake up dead debris for sure.  Fluff up soil a bit then seed with the best lawn mix seed you can find, ROLL, with a cheapo water filled roller.  Keep moist by watering shallowly 4 or 5 times a day...in 1 1/2 weeks to 2 weeks you will be doing your virgin mow.  Should be better.  Do not do any Ortho Weed and Feed if you want to grow SEED for lawn in that same soil within a month.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will do just that.  Do I still have time to do all this as this is early spring?

Comment: What is early spring like in NC?  How big of a lawn do you have?  If it is just a smallish lawn it might be good to think about getting a sod cutter (you can rent one), remove all the sod, use that sod turned over and stacked up as the beginning of plant beds.  You'll be dumping topsoil on top of the old sod.  The grass will quickly decompose.  If you find your sod has plastic framework, I'd get rid of the sod.  Such a waste.  At least replacing the worst grass with a uniform sod would look better.  Think about it.  Call around and ask for estimates...they are free. Check out seed spraying co.

Answer (score 0):

St Augustine would be very typical for zone 8 . It is put in as sod or plugged, not seed. In warm or hot weather ,the plugs fill in fairly fast. With plugs 18" apart, I had a yard fill in very well in one summer. For cool weather you can over seed with annual rye , it will die in warm weather and then the St Augustine will grow. It does need water in dry weather . A little standard lawn fertilizer will encourage it. I don't like it as much as blue grass , but blue grass does not grow in zone 8.